# jQuery - How to select last column of all rows in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Assuming I have a HTML table as follows (with the appropriate tr, td tags):

```
a1 | b1 | c1
a2 | b2 | c2
a3 | b3 | c3
a4 | b4 | c4

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>c1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>c2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a4</td>
    <td>b4</td>
    <td>c4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to select all the c* rows to perform an action on them.

Using the `$('td:last')` selector just selects the last td tag, i.e., c4.

I tried `$('tr > td:last')` which didn't work. What would be the correct selector in this case?

Comment: @AlexMorrise That works! Thanks. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: try $('tr td:last-child')

Comment: Just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:last` is a jQuery selector, but it will only select the **very last element of that type**. You're most likely looking for `:last-child`.

Similarly, `td:first-child` will get you the first cell, while `:first` gets you the first element of that type.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFXJ3/1/) for you to look at with all four examples.

Comment: It won't work as a straight CSS selector, but it *should* work as a jQuery selector. If you're developing for IE8 or below, it's best to do something like this: `$('td:last-child').addClass('last-child')` and reference it by `$('td.last-child')` instead.

Comment: You appear to be confusing `:last` for `:last-of-type`. `:last` is not a CSS selector, and the description you have given, which describes `:last-of-type` perfectly, does not quite describe how `:last` actually works.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. What I meant was, `:last` is a valid *jQuery* selector.

Comment: @BoltClock, `:last-of-type` doesn't always work that way, either. This example http://jsfiddle.net/DFXJ3/2/ in Google Chrome hides the last child and not the last of type `td`.

Comment: @Alex Morrise: Ah, that's where things get extra confusing - it's hiding the last element of type `td` in its parent, so it's basically `:last-child` of a specific type, which is expected behavior.

Comment: @BoltClock Right. But the jQuery selector `:last` can select the last of that type *in the DOM*, which is where it differs.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, to select every `td` that is the last child of its parent `tr`, use `:last-child` instead:

```
$('td:last-child')
```

The reason why the `:last` selector doesn't work is because it actually gives you the last element in the DOM that matches everything in the selector up to the point where it occurs:

- `$('td:last')` returns the last `td` element
- `$('tr > td:last')` returns the last `tr > td`

Since every `td` is `tr > td` by necessity, there is no difference in these two selectors.