# jQuery.dataTables : selected all rows except last column

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a table using `jQuery.dataTables`. I need to input date on the last column. But when I click input date row becomes not selected.

This code is for selected all rows.

Here is the DataTable.

```
var table = $('#tableRegister').DataTable({
                data: [],
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    targets: 0
                }],
                select: {
                    style: 'os',
                    selector: 'td:first-child'
                },
                order: [[1, 'asc']],
                columns: [
                    { data: "ACTION" },
                    { data: "ID" },
                    { data: "REGISTER_DATE" }
                ],
                rowCallback: function (row, data) { },
                filter: false,
                info: false,
                ordering: false,
                processing: true,
                retrieve: true
            });
```

```
  $('#table_name tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });
```

I draw the values of the table using ajax.

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.DataBadge._REG.length; i++) {
    table.row.add({
    "ID": e.DataBadge._REG[i]._ID,
    "REGISTER_DATE": `<input type='text' class='form-control datepicker2' id='register_date${i}'/>`
    }).draw();
}
```

How do I handle the last column to keep it selected?

Comment: You might need to use ":last-child Selector", which helps you to get the last child of your element. For more details have a look this : https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to select last column of all rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940565/jquery-how-to-select-last-column-of-all-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: @freedomn-m i'm new about this.. i don't know how to use it.. ill find some tutorial later.

Comment: No worries - I suspect it's your datepicker picker-button that's causing the problem - you can use `.stopPropagation()` to fix it.  But I don't know from your sample what the rendered HTML button would be to provide specifics.

Answer (score 0):

> when I click input date[,] row become not selected

it sounds like your click on the date picker is propagating up to the row handler

Here's a snippet showing a button being clicked also changing the row

```js
$("table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
tr.selected { background-color: yellow; }
td { padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td><input type='text'><button type='button'>pick</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td><input type='text'><button type='button'>pick</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td><input type='text'><button type='button'>pick</button></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and how to fix it using `.stopPropagation()` https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```js
$("table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});

$("table button").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

```css
tr.selected { background-color: yellow; }
td { padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td><input type='text'><button type='button'>pick</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td><input type='text'><button type='button'>pick</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td><input type='text'><button type='button'>pick</button></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can highlight the row's cells instead of the whole row and exclude the final column, by changing your click handler to `td` instead of `tr` then toggle on

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td").not(":last-child")
```

Example:

```js
$("table tr td").click(function() {
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).closest("tr").find("td").not(":last-child").addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
td.selected { background-color: yellow; }
td:not(:last-child) { cursor: pointer; }
td { padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```